# Developing two graphs in a single webpage with Plotly/Dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am having an issue developing two graphs connected to a single dropdown.

I think the code is working partially because the output does produces two blank graphs but not the right pie charts. I think the issue might be in connecting the callback to the graphh but I am not sure.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

all = df.Pillar.unique()

app.layout=html.Div(className='row', children=[
    html.H1("PRO Project Management dashboard"),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='pillar-choice',
                 options=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in all],
                 value=all,
                 multi=True),
    html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(id='graph1', style={'display':'inline-block', 'width': '50%'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph2', style={'display':'inline-block', 'width': '50%'})
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph1', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='pillar-choice', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph1(value_pillar):
        print(value_pillar)
        dff = df[df.Pillar.isin(value_pillar)]
        fig = px.pie(data_frame=dff, names='Pillar', values='Project No', title='Number of Projects by Pillars')
        return fig_1
    
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph2', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='pillar-choice', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph_2(value_pillar):
        print(value_pillar)
        dff = df[df.Pillar.isin(value_pillar)]
        fig = px.pie(data_frame=dff, names='Cadence', values='Project No', title='Number of Projects by Cadence')
        return fig_2
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated sample data to make code reproducible
- both your callbacks were returning and uninitiatlized variable.  Fixed this and two pie charts are linked to drop down in expected way

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Pillar":np.random.choice(["Enterprise","Department","Local"],20),"Project No":range(20),
                  "Cadence":np.random.choice(list("ABCD"),20)})

all = df.Pillar.unique()

app.layout=html.Div(className='row', children=[
    html.H1("PRO Project Management dashboard"),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='pillar-choice',
                 options=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in all],
                 value=all,
                 multi=True),
    html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(id='graph1', style={'display':'inline-block', 'width': '50%'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph2', style={'display':'inline-block', 'width': '50%'})
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph1', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='pillar-choice', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph1(value_pillar):
        print(value_pillar)
        dff = df[df.Pillar.isin(value_pillar)]
        fig = px.pie(data_frame=dff, names='Pillar', values='Project No', title='Number of Projects by Pillars')
        return fig
    
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph2', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='pillar-choice', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph_2(value_pillar):
        print(value_pillar)
        dff = df[df.Pillar.isin(value_pillar)]
        fig = px.pie(data_frame=dff, names='Cadence', values='Project No', title='Number of Projects by Cadence')
        return fig
    
# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked perfectly. I only changed 'fig_1' and 'fig_2' to fig. I maintained the rest of my code